# create file using ansible variable

Tags: ansible

i am trying to create file which will be use to create partition in windows.
I am using variables in below format.
additional_disks:

```
- drive_letter: E
  mount_point: TMP1
  disk_size: 7
  label: DBInstall
  block_size: 4096k
  datastore: vsanDatastoreCMP001
- drive_letter: F
  mount_point: TMP2
  disk_size: 9
  label: DBInstall1
  block_size: 4096k
  datastore: vsanDatastoreCMP001
- drive_letter: G
  mount_point: TMP3
  disk_size: 10
  label: DBInstall2
  block_size: 4096k
  datastore: vsanDatastoreCMP001
```

I am using below code:

```
- name: Testing Iteration
  copy:
    dest: /tmp/testtemp
    content: |
      {% for var in additional_disks %}
      select disk {{ my_idx | int +2 }}
      create partition primary
      assign letter "{{ item.drive_letter }}"
      format fs=ntfs label={{ item.label }} quick
      {% endfor %}
  with_items:
    - "{{ additional_disks }}"
  loop_control:
    index_var: my_idx
    label: " "
  delegate_to: localhost
```

Gettin output:

```
select disk 4
create partition primary
assign letter "G"
format fs=ntfs label=DBInstall2 quick
select disk 4
create partition primary
assign letter "G"
format fs=ntfs label=DBInstall2 quick
select disk 4
create partition primary
assign letter "G"
format fs=ntfs label=DBInstall2 quick
```

expected output:

```
select disk 2
create partition primary
assign letter E
format fs=ntfs label=DBInstall quick

select disk 3
create partition primary
assign letter F
format fs=ntfs label=DBInstall quick

select disk 4
create partition primary
assign letter G
format fs=ntfs label=DBInstall2 quick
```

Can you please help to get correct output

Answer (score 1):

here is my code: you can just leverage jinja2 loop.index, you do not have to use loop_control here, if you add `-D` option, you will find that `/tmp/testtemp` was overwrite three times.

```
    - name: Testing Iteration
      copy:
        dest: /tmp/testtemp
        content: |
          {% for var in additional_disks %}
          select disk {{ loop.index | int +2 }}
          create partition primary
          assign letter "{{ var.drive_letter }}"
          format fs=ntfs label={{ var.label }} quick
          {% endfor %}
      loop: "{{ additional_disks }}"
      #loop_control:
      #  index_var: my_idx
      #  label: " "
```

and also I do not recommend use copy module here, from the `ansible-doc copy`:

```
- content
        When used instead of `src', sets the contents of a file directly to the specified value.
        Works only when `dest' is a file. Creates the file if it does not exist.
        For advanced formatting or if `content' contains a variable, use the [template] module.
```

so if you want to use template instead of copy module, here is the template file

```
{% for var in additional_disks %}
select disk {{ loop.index | int +2 }}
create partition primary
assign letter "{{ var.drive_letter }}"
format fs=ntfs label={{ var.label }} quick
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for code. I have updated my variable little bit. I want create E drive then F and G drive will be created as mount path on E Drive.